# Convert Vulkan nvpro app to vulkan headless

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to convert [vk_raytrace](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytrace) to headless so that I can run it via commandline and dump rendered image. I am new to vulkan and saw that vulkan supports [headless surface](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_EXT_headless_surface.html). My first approach was to replace the surface [created](https://github.com/nvpro-samples/vk_raytrace/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L143) using glfw window to a headless surface. However, I get `VK_ERROR_EXTENSION_NOT_PRESENT` for `VK_EXT_headless_surface`. Next I tried removing surface and swapchain related logic and create frame buffers with image view as attachment. Haven't had any luck with that either.

Any pointers on this would be very helpful.

Comment: "*Haven't had any luck with that either.*" Well... did you do it correctly? Being "headless" is the *default* state of Vulkan; you have to expend effort to display stuff. Why are you using GLFW if you don't want a window?

Comment: No, I've removed glfw.

Comment: "It does not work" is not sufficient debugging information.